# Get and Put the same data to Redis in two different spring project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis, jhipster

I have a project generated by Jhipster, in the project I put the data to Redis using this:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Objects;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.core.business.sys.model.SessionInfo;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class SessionCacheManagerImpl implements SessionCacheManager {

    private final SessionService sessionService;


    public SessionCacheManagerImpl(SessionService sessionService
    ) {
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = Constants.CACHE.SESSION)
    public SessionInfo getSessionFromCache(String sessionId) {
        return sessionService
            .findOne(sessionId)
            .map(session -> {
                if (
                    !Objects.equals(session.getStatus(), STATUS.ONLINE) &&
                    !Objects.equals(session.getStatus(), STATUS.OFFLINE) ||
                    session.getExpiredTime().isBefore(Instant.now())
                ) {
                    return null;
                }
                return new SessionInfo()
                    .userAgent(session.getUserAgent())
                    .deviceMobileInfo(session.getDeviceMobileInfo())
                    .deviceId(session.getDeviceId())
                    .deviceIp(session.getDeviceIp())
                    .sessionId(session.getId());
            })
            .orElse(null);

    }
```

I have checked the project, and see that Jhispter integrated this to the project.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In the second project I get data using this:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.core.business.sys.model.SessionInfo;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class SessionCacheManagerServiceImpl implements SessionCacheManagerService {

    
    public SessionCacheManagerServiceImpl() {}

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = ConstantsCache.CACHE_NAME.SESSION)
    public SessionInfo getSessionFromCache(String sessionId) {
        log.info("getSessionFromCache: sessionId={}", sessionId);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I always got null result. The second project connect to Redis using

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I've been working on this problem 2 days, and I still don't know how to fix this problem. Can you give me some advice on this. Thanks you.